# ImageIO - get image Width and Height from loaded image

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, python-imageio

I need to get width and height of an image using imageio, loading an image into imageio with `imread`, how can I get the height and width of the image or in another word the resolution of the image? in the [documentation](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userapi.html#imageio.imread), it mentions it will return numpy array

example:

```
>>> from imageio import imread
>>> image_date = imread('c:/myImage.png')
```

when I print it out, I believe it returns a list of array of color

```
>>> print image_date
[[[ 18  23  16]
  [ 31  32  24]
  [ 34  29  23]
  ..., 
  [ 97  73  49]
  [ 95  73  50]
  [ 94  72  49]]

 [[ 23  24  18]
  [ 30  30  22]
  [ 36  29  21]
  ..., 
  [ 98  74  50]
  [ 95  73  50]
  [ 95  73  50]]

 [[ 32  27  21]
  [ 34  29  23]
  [ 37  28  21]
  ..., 
  [ 94  72  48]
  [ 97  72  50]
  [ 97  72  50]]

 ..., 
 [[ 43  35  24]
  [ 46  36  26]
  [ 48  36  24]
  ..., 
  [ 47  31  18]
  [ 47  31  18]
  [ 47  30  20]]

 [[ 59  56  47]
  [ 59  55  46]
  [ 59  50  41]
  ..., 
  [ 49  33  20]
  [ 48  32  19]
  [ 48  32  19]]

 [[114 115 107]
  [104 104  96]
  [100  93  85]
  ..., 
  [ 48  32  19]
  [ 48  32  19]
  [ 47  31  18]]]
```

any idea? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`image_date` is a numpy array so you can use the `shape` attribute. For example:

```
$ file black.png
black.png: PNG image data, 700 x 450, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

So `black.png` is a image with a width of 700 pixels and a height of 450 pixels.
Then in Python:

```
imageio.imread('black.png').shape
```

Outputs:

```
(450, 700, 3)
```

Comment: I see... that works!! so it means in your example 
there is an array of 3 (RGB) in each cell of width array and each width array is in each cell of height array or in another word imageio read image from top left to bottom right correct?

Comment: Yes, the numpy array is 3 dimensional, first being the height, second is the width, and third are the RGB channels.